# Social Media PHP Dynamic Meta Tags

Tags: php, facebook, seo, meta

I have a dynamic PHP website/blog that works fine to retrieve relevant information from my database: http://example.com/article.php?id='row id'

```
`<?php 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$results = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM main WHERE id = $id");
?>

<?php
while($row=$results->fetch())
{
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo ($row['headline']) ?></title>`
```

The above code works fine but when I try to populate facebook meta tags dynamically it does not work:

```
`<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo ($row['headline']) ?>" />`
```

Any idea why the echo of data works fine for the `<title>` etc but does not echo for the meta tags?

FB Open Graph Object Debugger says: "The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injection attacks. You need to process your GET variables before giving them to your database. Is something redefining/clearing $row between your output?

Comment: @jbes No I don't believe so. The above code is from my article.php page so when someone clicks on the headline on the index.php they arrive at article.php?id='row id of that article'

Comment: Can you provide the code that is between the code you have provided? From `</title>` to `<meta...>`? The reason for this is that the content of $row can't simply have 'disappeared' by itself. Something has happened there.

Answer (score 0):

can you post your rendered html code of facebook meta tags? I think the problem wasn't at fb meta tags, check your while loop and be sure that the echo of fb tags was inside the loop

Comment: the meta tags are within the `<head>` and also within the while loop. The issue I believe; is for some reason the echo works perfectly within the `<body> <title> <div> <p>` but isn't able to retrieve/populate the content within the meta tags!